# Axis Fault - HttpErrorCode:301 - Moved Permanently

Tags: axis

I have an old webservice application that always worked well. Suddenly, it stopped working and returns this error. I neither develop applications anymore, for years. I'm out of date.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

```
 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (301)Moved Permanently
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  301
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;301 Moved Permanently&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;center&gt;&lt;h1&gt;301 Moved Permanently&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/center&gt;
&lt;hr&gt;&lt;center&gt;nginx&lt;/center&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:301

(301)Moved Permanently
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at MRCS.ServiceANASoapStub.dadosHidrometeorologicos(ServiceANASoapStub.java:631)
    at MRCS.ServiceANASoapProxy.dadosHidrometeorologicos(ServiceANASoapProxy.java:50)
    at persistence.ConsultaPersisteTelemetrica._getDadosWebService(ConsultaPersisteTelemetrica.java:174)
    at persistence.ConsultaPersisteTelemetrica._persisteTelemetrica(ConsultaPersisteTelemetrica.java:100)
    at persistence.ConsultaPersisteTelemetrica.execute(ConsultaPersisteTelemetrica.java:42)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept such HTTP 301 codes and follow the redirects in your code. However, since you're no longer developing, the easiest way to fix this is to change the URL from http://xml.apache.org/axis/ to the new one that it redirects to, which is http://axis.apache.org/axis/.